# Menubar App - Is this right?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm trying to make an app, which, when the main window isn't visible, shows an icon in the menubar. However, I'm not sure about this code and whether it's ok. I get no errors and no warnings but after a few app switches back and forth between my app and another eg. Twitter or Safari I get

> Program received signal: 
>   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidResignActive:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
        statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] 
                       statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]
                      retain];
        [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
        [statusItem setEnabled:YES];

            //Set menubar item's tooltip
        [statusItem setToolTip:@"Nucleus"];
        [statusItem setMenu:theMenu];
            //Set the menubar item's title
        [statusItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:@"N"]]; 

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [statusItem release];
}
```

Comment: What's the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? You should be able to break on it in the debugger and see what line is causing this. You may also want to turn on NSZombieEnabled and see if that gives you anything.

Comment: Should you not be using `-[NSStatusBar removeStatusItem:]` to get rid of your status item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply replaced [statusItem release]; with [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] removeStatusItem:statusItem]; and that worked a treat. I don't want to completely release it as I still need it incase the user switches apps later. Thanks to @Kevin Ballard for that! :)

Answer (score 2):

If the app crashes when you're releasing the `statusItem` variable there's probability that assigned `menu` attribute gets over-released. I'm not sure about this since I don't know here `theMenu` variable is coming from.